# Get result of add impulse if object was not moved

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So, lets say my character has the ability to push "movable" objects. This is alredy implemented and working as desired.

But I want to make the characher be pushed back if he tries to push an object that is hitting a wall or an immovable object, is there a way to see if my add impulse had any effect?

Or a best way to do is some ray casts on the movable object boundaries to see if is touching any other thing?

Comment: I expect that the location of the `movable` changes whenever you add impulse unless the item is stuck in front of a wall. Can you save your item last location and whenever you add impulse you check the location and compare it with the last saved location?

Answer (score 1):

For characters you can use Launch Character. It's like adding velocity giving a specific direction. Add Impulse is intended to be used with Objects that simulate physics.
Just Launch the Character to a direction opposite the direction it's touching. You can use Dot Product between Character Velocity and the Object Face (forward).